# Joining SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a customer table that has primary information about the customer like, name, lastname,password,… I have a Address, Email, Phone table that has for example 3 kinds of address , 2 phone number, 2 email address for each customer. I have a Type table that TypeID and Type_Group,Type_Value. For example:

```
  TypeID           Type_Group       Type_Value
    1               Address          Work
    2               Address          Home
    3               Address          mailing
    4               Email            Primary
    5               Email            secondary
```

I know how to join customer table with address, Email and phone table. I don't know how to join the Address, phone,Email with type Table.

This is my Query:

```
     SELECT
      cc.[Customer_ID]
        ,[Account_Number]
        ,[First_Name]
        ,[Middle_Name]
        ,[Last_Name]
        ,[Password]
     ,ce.[Email]
     ,cph.Phone_Number
     ,ca.Address_1
     ,ca.Address_2
     ,ca.City
     ,ca.State
     ,ca.Zip
     ,tp.Type_Desc

   FROM [CustomerPortal].[dbo].[Customer] cc WITH (NOLOCK) 
   left join [CustomerPortal].[dbo].Customer_Email ce WITH (NOLOCK) on cc.Customer_ID =    ce.Customer_ID
   left join [CustomerPortal].[dbo].Customer_Address ca WITH (NOLOCK) on cc.Customer_ID =cp.Customer_ID
   left join [CustomerPortal].[dbo].Customer_Phone cph WITH (NOLOCK) on cc.Customer_ID =cph.Customer_ID

   WHERE cc.Customer_ID=@Customer_ID
```

This is Tables:

this is customer Table:

```
         (PRIMARY KEY)[Customer_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                      [Account_Number] [int] NULL,
                      [First_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
                      [Middle_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
```

Customer Address Table:

```
                      [dbo].[Customer_Address](
                      primary key[Customer_Address_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
                      Fkey  [Customer_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
                      [Address_1] [varchar](100) NULL,
                      [Address_2] [varchar](100) NULL,
                      [City] [varchar](100) NULL,
                      [State] [varchar](10) NULL,
                      [Zip] [varchar](10) NULL,
                      Fkey  [Address_Type] [int] NULL,
```

CustomerEmail Table:

```
               [dbo].[Customer_Email](
          PKey [Customer_Email_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
          Fkey [Customer_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
               [Email] [varchar](50) NULL,
        Fkey   [Email_Type] [int] NULL,
```

Customer Phone Table:

```
    PK       [dbo].[Customer_Phone](
    FK       [Customer_Phone_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
             [Customer_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
             [Phone_Number] [bigint] NULL,
   FK        [Phone_Type] [int] NULL,
```

Type Table:

```
      PK  [dbo].[Type_XREF](
       [Type_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [Type_Group] [varchar](25) NULL,
       [Type_Value] [varchar](50) NULL,
       [Type_Desc] [varchar](100) NULL,
```

I am not sure how to add join to Type Table, any thing I try produce me several Rows, as I want to have 1 row for customer with name, All related Home address,All related mailing address, primary email,secondary email,.... So all customer info in 1 line of record.

Comment: This is definitely ms sql server, not MySQL. [dbo] is a sql server construct.

Comment: Do you want to be able to assign Customer_Address.type of `secondary` or a Customer_Email.type of `Work`?

Comment: I hope you're not storing the actual password in a DB column. You meant the password hash, right?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn no I know I shouldn't:) I encrypt then save it.

Comment: encrypt != hash. encrypt isn't good enough for passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join each of the tables to the type table seperately, since their Type ID will correspond to one of the IDs in the type table.  Even though the types are mixed in the table, each element in their respective table would reasonable have a logical type assigned to it.  I'll just make an assumption on the format that you want to display the Type in and the name of the table:

```
SELECT
  cc.[Customer_ID]
    ,[Account_Number]
    ,[First_Name]
    ,[Middle_Name]
    ,[Last_Name]
    ,[Password]
 ,ce.[Email]
 ,cph.Phone_Number
 ,ca.Address_1
 ,ca.Address_2
 ,ca.City
 ,ca.State
 ,ca.Zip
 ,tp.Type_Desc
 ,te.Type_Group + '-' + te.Type_Value as [EmailType]
 ,ta.Type_Group + '-' + ta.Type_Value as [AddressType]
 ,tph.Type_Group + '-' + tph.Type_Value as [PhoneType]

 FROM [CustomerPortal].[dbo].[Customer] cc WITH (NOLOCK) 

left join [CustomerPortal].[dbo].Customer_Email ce WITH (NOLOCK) on cc.Customer_ID =    ce.Customer_ID
left join [CustomerPortal].[dbo].Customer_Address ca WITH (NOLOCK) on cc.Customer_ID =cp.Customer_ID
left join [CustomerPortal].[dbo].Customer_Phone cph WITH (NOLOCK) on cc.Customer_ID =cph.Customer_ID
left join [dbo].Type_Table te on te.ID = ce.Type
left join [dbo].Type_Table ta on ta.ID = ca.Type
left join [dbo].Type_Table tph on tph.ID = cph.Type
```

Comment: Thanks @Bcpouli for your response, this give me 2 line of record with same info jyst different phone Number, can I have one line of record with 2 different column as Phonework, phone Home.

Comment: with this way of join I get duplicate records.